# How to disable network option in Windows explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012, group-policy, smb-conf

It's a little bit more complicated, I want to hide or deny use of the network location in Windows explorer to domain users, but I also need to give them access to mapped network devices and I can't disable network discovery because every user has a shared folder for update backup and scanner purposes.

Here's a screen capture to show what I want:

[image: Network folder unavailable to the user]

The idea is prevent users from wandering the net. Basic and curious users at least.

Comment: Security through obscurity?

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2010/12/06/disabling-network-discoverynetwork-resources/ has a few ways to disable this.  The simplest group policy for me to understand is adding firewall rules to block the ports.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the network node, you can create the following registry value on the computers:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\NonEnum\{F02C1A0D-BE21-4350-88B0-7367FC96EF3C}

Type: REG_DWORD

Data: 1

This will prevent Windows Explorer from listing this node.